# How can I split a '%Y%m%d%H%i%s' column into two columns: one that contains %Y%m%d% and the that contains H%i%s in hive?

Tags: hive, impala

I have a column displaying  '%Y%m%d%H%i%s' (e.g. 20150125145900) How can I convert it into two columns, one "ymd" and another "his" (e.g 2015/01/25   and 14:59:00)?

Comment: By all means use date/timestamp types or at least ISO format yyyy-MM-dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hive**

```
select  ts[0] as year
       ,ts[1] as hour

from   (select  split(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20150125145900','yyyyMMddHHmmss')
                    ,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),' ') as ts
        ) t
```

---

```
+------------+----------+
|    year    |   hour   |
+------------+----------+
| 2015-01-25 | 14:59:00 |
+------------+----------+
```

**Impala**

```
select  split_part(ts,' ',1) as year
       ,split_part(ts,' ',2) as hour

from   (select  from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20150125145900','yyyyMMddHHmmss')
                    ,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as ts
        ) t
;
```

---

```
+------------+----------+
| year       | hour     |
+------------+----------+
| 2015-01-25 | 14:59:00 |
+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, I appreciate it.  I can see it works great in impala with the example, but when I replace  '20150125145900' for the name of the column, I get  "Your query has the following error(s):

AnalysisException: No matching function with signature: unix_timestamp(BIGINT, STRING)." Any idea what is causing this? I really appreciate it.

Comment: The first argument should be a string and your column is a bigint. You should cast it to string.

Answer (score 0):

`select datetime[0] as`year`,datetime[1] as`hour`from (select split(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20150125145900','yyyyMMddhhmmss'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),' ') as datetime)e`

```
year          hour
2015-01-25  02:59:00
```

Comment: ...and why don't you use a single split in the inner query?

Comment: we can write single split but because of clear understand i wrote like that with single split iam pasting below